# Can't remove Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I get two problem by using gestures. First I want remove a gesture called "panRecognizer" on double tap, but it doesn't work. Second Problem I use the panRecognizer to move the view but I can't move to the outer edges it stops 200 or 150 px before I reached the edge from the view.

Here is my code:

```
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController?.gestureRecognizers
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(miningCatalouge.doubleTapped(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func doubleTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(miningCatalouge.handlePan(_:)))
    let curScale = self.view!.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.scale.x")!.floatValue

    if (curScale == 1) {

        pageViewController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3)
        panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

    } else {

    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(512, 391)
    pageViewController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

        //Don´t removed the gesture "panRecognizer"
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    }
    print("doubleTapped")
}

func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)



    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        // 1
        let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.view)
        let magnitude = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y))
        let slideMultiplier = magnitude / 200
        // print("magnitude: \(magnitude), slideMultiplier: \(slideMultiplier)")

        // 2
        let slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMultiplier     //Increase for more of a slide
        // 3
        var finalPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                 y:recognizer.view!.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor))
        // 4
        finalPoint.x = min(max(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width)
        finalPoint.y = min(max(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height)

        // 5
        UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(slideFactor),
                                   delay: 0,
                                   // 6
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
            animations: {recognizer.view!.center = finalPoint },
            completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `doubleTapped` message get printed?

Comment: Yes it printed in console....

Comment: What the error you got? How do you know the gesture is not removed?

Comment: after I double tapped again the scale changed to 1 but the panGesture is still active.

Comment: oh i see the problem. Your `panGesture` is a local variable inside the method. It will be a `new` one every time the method is called. So even if you removed the `old` one, the new one will be added and will be there still. You need to save it as a instance variable instead.

Comment: Yes your are rigth now it works. I initiallized the panGesture in viewDidLoad now it works thank you so much J.Wang

Comment: @J.Wang You should write an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for gesture in view.gestureRecognizers!
        {
            if let recognizer = gesture as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
                view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
```

Hope this code could help

Comment: this is a good way to remove all gestures from view but in my case i don´t won´t remove all gestures, but J.Wang found the solution for my problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from J.Wang:

```
    class miningCatalouge: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

        // I created a new Variable
        var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController?.gestureRecognizers
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(miningCatalouge.doubleTapped(_:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
//initialized action to panRecognizer
            panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(miningCatalouge.handlePan(_:)))

        }

        func doubleTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            let curScale = self.view!.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.scale.x")!.floatValue

            if (curScale == 1) {

                pageViewController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3)
                panRecognizer!.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
                panRecognizer!.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
                self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)

            } else {

                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
                self.view.center = CGPointMake(512, 391)
                pageViewController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
                self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)

            }
            print("doubleTapped")
        }

        func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
            if let view = recognizer.view {
                view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                      y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            }
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

            if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

                let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.view)
                let magnitude = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y))
                let slideMultiplier = magnitude / 200
                // print("magnitude: \(magnitude), slideMultiplier: \(slideMultiplier)")

                let slideFactor = 0.15 * slideMultiplier     //Increase for more of a slide

                let finalPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                         y:recognizer.view!.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor))

                UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(slideFactor),
                                           delay: 0,
                                           // 6
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
                    animations: {recognizer.view!.center = finalPoint },
                    completion: nil)
            }
        }
```